# POST rendered text by Razor in ASP.NET MVC to server

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a situation where I make a with some Razor. This is pretty standard, so imagine something like:

```
<div>
    <strong>Undertegnede myndige skyldner</strong>:<br /><br />
        @Model.ContractText.DebtorName, @Model.ContractText.DebtorFullAddress
        @foreach (var reminder in Model.DemandStructure.ReminderFees_Lines)
        {
            @reminder.Label @: @reminder.Amount.ToCurrency()<br />
        }
</div>
```

This becomes a nice piece of text.

What I want to do, is to POST this generated text, and store it on the server.

**Possible solutions**

Now, I could of course just generate this string on the server, but then I would loose the nice formatting of Razor.

I could use some templating language - but I am not familiar with anything that is easy and solves my problem to use on the server side?

Maybe it makes sense to wrap this in some kind of input field so it's POST-ed to server?

Does anyone have a simple and smart solution for how to POST a generated text-string to the server?

Comment: You could put it in a separate Razor file and render that on the server.

Comment: @SLaks Do you have a code snippet example? Or an idea what to search for? Sounds easy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean post the text to the server in relation to a user action on the page? 
 If not, certainly do it server-side instead, and even in that case while yes, you potentially could wrap it in a form element (or probably wrap a copy of the text in for example a hidden element) and that will be submitted with any form submits - you probably shouldn't do this for a number of reasons;

1. The user will be able to edit the text before it is send to the server, and it looks like they shouldn't be able to, as then they could change the Amount value before it is stored
2. It will be hard to encode the newlines (they are br elements in your HTML but these don't post correctly to a newline in a string so you would have to convert them, or use a textarea instead)
3. It generates unnecessary network traffic.

What you should probably do is simply store it on the server-side code, using a format string to create the same resultant text;

```
var theText = $"Undertegnede myndige skyldner:{Envionment.NewLine}{Envionment.NewLine}{Model.ContractText.DebtorName}, {Model.ContractText.DebtorFullAddress}
        {String.Join(Environment.NewLine, Model.DemandStructure.ReminderFees_Lines})";
```

Comment: You're totally right, the user should not be able to edit it.. And you're right, the user could in theory change the change before POSTing if it was in a hiddenfield or so. But the text is very long (shortened it above) and putting it all in a long string.format, is just very error-prone. I guess the Razor file and render it on the server is the way forward?

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard Just a note - If you render the Razor file you'll still face the problem of having to encode any HTML elements into normal text - i.e. <br/> doesn't create a newline in a normal string, only when rendered by a browser. Are you sure you want to store the whole TEXT on the server? And not just the component variables? It seems redundant to store this as a string...